# Get the sum of the outerHeight of all elements of the same class

Tags: jquery

I think this is a pretty straightforward problem but...

```
var outerHeight = $('.profile').outerHeight();
$("#total-height").text(outerHeight + 'px');
```

Right now the var `outerHeight` gives me the outerHeight of only the first element with the class `.profile`.

How can I get the sum of the outerHeights of *all* elements with the class `.profile`?

Comment: You've asked a few question here at SO but you've never accepted an answer. You should accept an answer (check mark next to the numbers) if one of the answers helped you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Loop through each matching element and add up the outerheights:

```
var outerHeight = 0;
$('.profile').each(function() {
  outerHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
});
$("#total-height").text(outerHeight + 'px');
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's the straight forward solution. Just loop through the elements of the jQuery object summing up the `outerHeight()`s.

```
var total = 0;
$('.profile').each(function(){
    total += $(this).outerHeight();
});
// total is good here
```

The important thing is that all jQuery getters only return the value of the first element in the jQuery set but you can add them yourself.

And here's a roundabout but cool way of doing it http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/bKtAn/6/

```
// You can use a jQuery object as the `this` param in `Array.prototype` functions
var totalHeight = Array.prototype.reduce.call($('span'), function(a,b){
   // The first param is either the default value (passed into reduce)
   // or the result of the last call of this reducing function
   return a + $(b).outerHeight();
}, 0);
```

Which could be generalized as a `reduce` and made into a plugin like: http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/bKtAn/9/

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.reduce = function(cb, init) {  
      return Array.prototype.reduce.call(this, function(a,b){
            return cb(a, b);
      }, init);  
    }
})(jQuery);

const total = $('span').reduce(
   (accumulator, current) => accumulator + $(current).height(),
   0
);
console.log({total});
```

I think I went a bit overboard, sorry, I got excited, but these code snippets teach you a lot about JS and even a bit of jQuery

Comment: @downvoter: It'd be nice to explain why you thought this answer wasn't useful!

Answer (score 6):

`$("selector")` is already a collection.  **Access directly the `.outerHeight()`** or any other method like `.height()`

```
var total = 0;
$("div").outerHeight(function(i, v){
   total += v;
});

alert( total ); // Just to test
```

```js
var total = 0;

$("div").outerHeight(function(i, v){ total += v; });

alert( total );
```

```css
div{background:#eee; margin:3px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:100px;">100px</div>
<div>just lots of breaklines :)<br><br><br><br></div>
<div style="height:200px;">200px</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var total = 0;
$('.profile').each(function() {
     total += $(this).outerHeight();
});

$("#total-height").text(total + 'px');
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery functions that don't return a jQuery object operate only on the first member of a list.

If you want to iterate over all `.profile` elements, you can use `.each()`

```
var totalHeight = 0;
$('.profile').each(function(i, e) {
    totalHeight += $(e).outerHeight();
});
```

Comment: The params passed to `$('selector').each` are not the same as the params passed to `$.each`. There's no `e` parameter, `this` refers to the HTML element

Comment: You are completely wrong. http://api.jquery.com/each/ even lists the signature as `.each( function(index, Element) )` You can test to see that `e` exists if you like. (`this` is available as well)

Comment: My bad, I assumed it from the description on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ "The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), " They are not the same but they both do pass the element as the second parameter. The only difference is that $(selector).each() sets `this` to the same thing as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var outerHeightTotal = 0;
$('.profile').each(function(){
  outerHeightTotal += $(this).outerHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) an array of the native elements and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the sum.

This might be cleaner because it's one line without the need to declare a variable in advance.

```js
const height = $('div').get().reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.offsetHeight, 0);
console.log(height);
```

```css
.child1 {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.child3 {
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="child1"></div>
<div class="child2"></div>
<div class="child3"></div>
```

This approach can be used without jQuery of course. The `[...]` thing is to convert `NodeList` to an array of elements)

```js
const height = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')].reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.offsetHeight, 0);
console.log(height);
```

```css
.child1 {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.child3 {
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="child1"></div>
<div class="child2"></div>
<div class="child3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also be lazy as me and introduce a new jQuery function that will do all the work for you, like this:

```
(function($) {    
    $.fn.sumOfOuterHeights = function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $(this).each(function () {
            sum += $(this).outerHeight();
        });
        return sum;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And then use it in your code wherever you like it:

```
var height = $('.a, .b, .c').sumOfOuterHeights();
```

For me it is also a little bit more readable and DRY if you use it often.

Answer (score 0):

More modern option:

```
let height = 0
$('.profile').each((i, el) => height += $(el).outerHeight())
```